# Reverse Gecoding to return full formatted address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm using reverse geococoding to read coordinates and convert them to a street address. 
The code i have works but my problem is that it only returns the suburb and town is it possible to format it in a way that it returns full address  number - street - suburb - town - country.

```
 // Read coordinates and convert to Readible Address
function codeLatLng() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
//var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
//var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
var lat = parseFloat(latitude);
var lng = parseFloat(longitude);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
                       $("#txtCurrentAdd").val(results[1].formatted_address)

            //infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
            //infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
            alert('No results found');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: why did my question get minused?

Comment: every question has been asked before in the world stop being stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to change results[1] for results[0]? From [Google Geocode Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en-us) docs:

```
results[0].formatted_address: "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
results[1].formatted_address: "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
results[2].formatted_address: "New York 11211, USA",
results[3].formatted_address: "Kings, New York, USA",
results[4].formatted_address: "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
results[5].formatted_address: "New York, New York, USA",
results[6].formatted_address: "New York, USA",
results[7].formatted_address: "United States"
```